# C# MVC display items from sharepoint list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

So...i created a Sharepoint Add-in (C# MVC) to get list information and create/update items. I've done the creating/updating in the past, not gonna tackle that now.

My problem here is displaying the list items into the MVC View. What i've done so far ->

I created a model (class) with the information that i'll show in the table:

```
public class IRFItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string StartDate { get; set; }
    public string EndDate { get; set; }
    //public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

In the same file (for the sake of keeping my tests compact) i also added a way to get the items i need:

```
     public static List<IRFItem> GetItems(SharePointContext spContext, CamlQuery camlQuery)
    {

        List<IRFItem> items = new List<IRFItem>();
        //var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext.Current);

        using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPAppWeb())
        {
            if (clientContext != null)
            {
                List irfList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("IRF");
                ListItemCollection irfListItems = irfList.GetItems(camlQuery);
                clientContext.Load(irfListItems);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                if (irfListItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var irfListItem in irfListItems)
                    {
                    items.Add(
                        new IRFItem
                        {
                            Title = irfListItem["Title"].ToString(),
                            StartDate = irfListItem["StartDate"].ToString(),
                            EndDate = irfListItem["EndDate"].ToString(),
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    items.Add(
                    new IRFItem
                    {
                        Title = "Empty",
                        StartDate = "Empty",
                        EndDate = "Empty"
                    });
                }

            }
        }

        return items;
    }
```

In my custom controller (called SharepointController so i dont mess up with the default ones) i added this ->

```
    // GET: Sharepoint
    [SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(HttpContext);

        ViewBag.Username = SharePointService.GetUserName(spContext);

        CamlQuery queryProducts = new CamlQuery();
        queryProducts.ViewXml =
           @"<View>  
         <ViewFields><FieldRef Name='StartDate' /><FieldRef Name='LinkTitle' /><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Author' /><FieldRef Name='EndDate' /><FieldRef Name='ID' /></ViewFields> 
  </View>";

        List<IRFItem> items = SharePointService.GetItems(spContext, queryProducts);

        //SharePointService.GetItems(spContext, queryProducts);
        return View(items);
    }
```

And finally my desired view contains->

```
                    @foreach (AddinTest1Web.Models.IRFItem irfItem in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@irfItem.Title</td>
                            <td>@irfItem.StartDate</td>
                            <td>@irfItem.EndDate</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
```

I get no errors, but my table is always empty...I even added that else part in GetItems to create an item that shows empty just so i know if its a sharepoint related problem or something else. My MVC experience isn't much to be honest (just started learning it a week ago, but im the kind of guy that learns by doing).

Does anyone see any problems here? I've followed a tutorial for this and made my own little changes.

Ref: https://www.chakkaradeep.com/2013/10/18/building-apps-for-sharepoint-with-mvc/

Any kind of tip will be highly appreciated, thx.

EDIT: I jumped over the error by giving the application more permissions (to list & web just to be safe) and i am getting back results, however i am unable to create the items because executeQuery does not finish on time. Any idea how to delay that? I remember i had a bigggg problem with tasks in the past so i have no idea where to start here.

Comment: Think the question should be moved to SharePoint specific site https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Place a debug point at `foreach (var irfListItem in irfListItems)` and see if SharePoint is returning any values in **FieldValues**. It will be a dictionary.

Comment: Hmmm...i did. I'm not very experienced in debugging, but i assume that seeing "Count 0" means the app got no items from SP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i fixed the problem (been fighting with this for hours and it was so damn simple i wanna punch myself right now).

In case anyone encounters this ->

Why my list didnt get any items (even tho no erorrs) -> Not enough permissions given to the app. Fixed by giving full list permissions and full web permissions.

Why my foreach was giving an error -> Apparently one column had a different name. I figured that out by trying this code (which apparently is better cause it throws an error, unlike getting everything from the list) ->

```
            clientContext.Load(irfListitems, 
                itemss => itemss.Include(
                    item => item["Title"],
                    item => item["StartDate"],
                    item => item["EndDate"]
                    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things I see from debugging.

I would move the code GetItems() to separate Helper class and then put a breakpoint in it to see if it is firing.

If you are not getting any error and return data is always empty, then that means that some part of the code is not getting executed (Sync or async issue?)

Comment: Code gets executed (i tested by trying to get the sharepoint site name/description and append those to the items). Its a problem with getting the list for some reason....i think i'll post this to the sharepoint stackexchange, maybe i'll find someone who encountered something like this.

Comment: Apparently the code did get executed, but it didnt have enough permissions to retrieve the list items (weird, i remember it giving an erorr for that). Now i got the items, but the foreach gets in too fast and i cant append anything due to it not being initialized, any idea how i can delay that?